# Возможно ли оставить выполнение функции в главном потоке

Tags: android, потоки-данных, java

Здравствуйте, предположим есть такой код:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.main);
   text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text); 
   text.setText("Привет");
   i=0;
   do {
     COUNT();
     i++;
  } while (i < 10); 
}
```

В текстовое поле пишется слово "привет" и выполняется цикл, в котором 10 раз выполняется функция `COUNT()`. Но при таком коде, только выполняется цикл, а в текстовое поле ничего не пишется. Т.е. открывается приложение и белый экран ( нету верстки, которая в `xml` - ни фона, ни кнопок, ни текстового поля, в которое пишется слово). Идет выполнение цикла, в котором выполняется функция `COUNT()`. Я понимаю почему так происходит. Знаю, что лучше поместить выполнение цикла в `Async Task`, но вопрос вот в чем: а возможно ли как-нибудь оставить выполнение функции в главном потоке ( т.е. не менять ничего), запись    `text.setText("Привет");` поместить например в `Async task`? или в другой поток, чтобы они одновременно выполнялись? Или есть другие способы ?

Answer (score 4):

Работу с UI в другой поток вынести никак нельзя, UI поток на то и UI поток.
Если все таки вынести, то сразу начнет ругаться.

Comment: А Вы пробовали? Это не невозможно, это не рекомендуется. Из стороннего потока можно преспокойно управлять статическими переменными UI потока (достаточно контролы объявить как статик волейтил). Это не правильно, но это работает.

Answer (score 4):

Наоборот.

Вычисление медленной функции `COUNT` надо выгрузить в async task, а работа с UI должна оставаться в одном и том же потоке.

Делайте так:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text); 
    text.setText("Привет");

    new AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                COUNT();
                publishProgress(i);
                if (isCancelled()) break;
            }
            return null;
        }
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
            text.setText("Выполнено: " + progress[0]);
        }
    }.execute();
}
```